# Can you put your PS4 hard-drive into your PS4 Slim without issue?

Tags: ps4

I want to keep the saved data and down loaded games on my hard-drive when I sell my PS4,  so that when I buy a PS4 Slim I can just pop my PS4 hard-drive into the new one. Will any issues arise? Is there a different hard drive format for a PS4 Slim? Is it incompatible?

Comment: This question is on-topic for this stack. As mentioned in the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), gaming-specific hardware is on-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this comment and answers](https://blog.eu.playstation.com/2016/11/09/how-to-transfer-your-data-from-ps4-to-ps4-pro/#comment-741545) on the PlayStation blog you CANNOT just swap the drives over.   -  The Hard drives are encrypted and keyed to the system they are in.

You can however back everything up to an external drive and then copy this data to the new system once you have it.  full instruction on how to do this can be found in the [PS4 user guide](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/gb/ps4/settings/backup.html)